# Assign constant to a final class and call its constants

Tags: php

I have the following code and I am using php 5.5.6

**product.php**

```
class product {

    const STATUS = status;

    function __construct(){}

    public function printStatus($status){
        echo $status;
    }
}

final class status {
    const BROKEN = "br";
    const AVAILABLE = "av";
}
```

**index.php**

```
include("product.php");

$pr = new product();
$st = product::STATUS;
$pr->printStatus($st::BROKEN);
```

The above code gives as an output `br`, which is the expected

**index2.php**

```
include("product.php");

$pr = new product();
$pr->printStatus(product::STATUS::BROKEN);
```

The above code gives the following error `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '::' (T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM) in ...` which means that line `$pr->printStatus(product::STATUS::BROKEN);`

Does anyone know why this is happening? Is there a php limitation?

Comment: This is incorrect: `const STATUS = status;` Read about PHP syntax.

Comment: That simply won't work. There's no way to make it work that way.

Comment: @Phantom incorrect yes, but silently guessed to what he means if E_NOTICE is not shown

Comment: @Phantom php interpreter allows it, i also thought that it is incorrect because you can not assign constant 'at runtime'. But as you can see in `index.php` it works

Comment: @colburton thats correct

Comment: I don't know what you want to do with this code: `product::STATUS::BROKEN`. You can't set a constant at runtime, that's not possible. Then it is a variable and no constant...

Comment: @Yannici my code is just for testing reason. And I made the observation I am describing

Comment: @MarkBaker That would be wrong, too. Because `status` class doesn't have a constant named `STATUS`.

Answer (score 0):

The following code is wrong:

```
$pr->printStatus(product::STATUS::BROKEN);
```

You can't set a constant at runtime. Maybe it would be better you're using a variable in class `product` like:

```
public $STATUS = status::AVAILABLE;
```

Then you can do something like this:

```
<?php
include("product.php");

$pr = new product();
$pr->STATUS = status::BROKEN;
$pr->printStatus($pr->STATUS);
?>
```

With that you can set the STATUS of a product object whenever you want.

Comment: As you can see in `index.php` I am successfully 'setting a constant at runtime'. Using the `$st` variable in my code code it works. The `product::STATUS::BROKEN` is a 'shorthand' of assigning  `product::STATUS` to a temporary value and the access its constant like this `$st::BROKEN`

Comment: No, that isn't possible. You don't "set" the constant. You're constant is the `status` class. And you're giving out the BROKEN constant of the `status` class. You're not setting anything. So you can do it like `$pr->printStatus(status::BROKEN);` But with this you aren't setting the STATUS constant of the product object.

Comment: Yes, I understand. 'setting' was a wrong choice of word.